# How to remove all HTML tags except anchor tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-2.0

Is there any method to remove HTML tags from a string without removing anchor tag links?

For example, this is my input:

```
 <html>
     <body>
      <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
      <p>This is test content </p>
      <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
     </body>
  </html>
```

And my desired output:

http://www.yahoo.com Yahoo

This is test content

http://www.google.com Google

Answer (score 6):

Use [Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize).

Tags and attributes (only the mentioned tags and attributes are allowed, nothing else).

```
<%= sanitize @article.body, tags: %w(table tr td), attributes: %w(id class style) %>
```

Here's the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize).

Comment: And if you want to use it not only in views, I suggest to look at [Loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) gem - it does most of the work in new, more secure, sanitizers introduced Rails 4.2 and can be used without them. It is also based at Nokogiri.

Comment: @reko very helpful. However my final output should be text(stripping all html tags) keeping the links only. Does gem has any methods for this? eg input: <html><body><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a><p>test</p><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></body></html>                                      Output:  http://www.google.com Google test http://www.yahoo.com Yahoo

Comment: I dont think the gem does that.jQuery should do the job. Get the src value and add it before the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nokogiri parser](http://www.nokogiri.org/) to parse your HTML and save the value of the `href` attribute whenever you encounter an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research this gem solves my problem:
https://github.com/premailer/premailer

But i had to modify the it's html_to_plain_text module to not remove ruby variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nokigiri to parse HTML.

```
x = Nokogiri::HTML(html_content)
output = []
x.at_css('body').children.each do |tag|
    if tag.class == Nokogiri::XML::Element 
        output << tag.attributes if tag.respond_to?(:attributes)
        output << tag.children if tag.respond_to?(:children)
    end
end
puts output
[{"href"=>#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fef80461c98 name="href" value="http://www.yahoo.com">}, [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fef804617d4 "Yahoo">], [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fef80461310 "This is test content ">], {"href"=>#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fef80461054 name="href" value="http://www.google.com">}, [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fef80460b7c "Google">]]
```

You can format the output array as you want